# Fixing Deprecation Warning

Tags: c++, mingw

When compiling the below code, it gives me a warning, namely
`deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'`.

In what ways is it possible to remove the message (without explicitly suppressing the warning)?
I tried casting with `(const char*)`, but to no avail.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    typedef int * (*MyDownloadToUrl)(void*, char*, char*, DWORD, void*);
    HINSTANCE LibHnd = LoadLibrary("Urlmon.dll");
    MyDownloadToUrl MyDownloadFunction =  (MyDownloadToUrl)GetProcAddress(LibHnd,"URLDownloadToFileA");

    MyDownloadFunction(0, "http://MyWebsite.com", "Webpage.htm", 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: @J C Did you try `typedef int * (*MyDownloadToUrl)(void*, const char*, const char*, DWORD, void*);` ?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the signature of [URLDownloadToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) actually does use constant strings.

Comment: @vsoftco That did the trick. Apparently I added `const` to the wrong argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `const_cast<char*>("my string literal")` to get rid of the warning.  In C++03 implicit conversion from a string literal (which is a `const char*`) to `char*` is deprecated.  In C++11 such an implicit conversion is an error.

In this case though, `URLDownloadToFile` takes arguments of type `LPCTSTR`, which is defined as either `const wchar_t*` or `const char*` depending on the `UNICODE` prepossessor directive.